# How to publish website using Kompozer on localhost with WAMP server?

Tags: localhost, wamp, publish

I am switching from Dreamweaver to Kompozer, in the whole going open source way. I have recently installed the latest WAMP Server. I have searched all over google using various search queries but still no result.

My question is:

How do you publish a web page or a web site using Kompozer on localhost with WAMP server?

If it's not possible, then please tell me if there is another way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by publish?

Comment: Kompozer has a publish button which uploads to a server. But I don't know what settings to input in the dialog box?

Comment: Well as WAMPServer and the localhost environment is on the same machine you probably dont need to. Create the source directly into the folder you are using under `\wamp\www\???` then its good for testing. Once its tested and working use the publish to move it to the live site

Comment: That's my problem. What are the pubish settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kompozer requires a FTP server to upload files. WAMP does not come with a FTP server. So, instead install a FTP server and point the host directory of WAMP, www, to be the FTP root directory. Then, just add the details of FTP server to Kompozer and it would do the trick.